# as3 dynamic class convert in runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, class, dynamic, runtime

This is what I got:

```
public var myDynamicClass:MovieClip;
```

I want to convert it to this class in run time.

```
public class MyWishClass extends MovieClip{
    public var myId:String;
}
```

one solution is to do the next thing:

```
   myDynamicClass.myId = null as String;
```

The problem with that is that I am getting false in the next line:

```
myDynamicClass instanceOf MyWishClass
```

What can I do?

**EDIT:**
Basically I am changing dynamic class at run time, by adding him properties and I want to cast it to another class that already got those properties.

Comment: Are you trying to do some [type conversions?](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html)

Comment: @SamDeHaan yeah, but I am creating my class at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it,

The answer is no :( it's not possible...

The only work around I did, is to create new MyWishClass and pass myDynamicClass, to him, so he is basically warping him.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understanding your question but..

Can you not just do this?

```
public var myDynamicClass:MyWishClass;
/* --- */
myDynamicClass = new MyWishClass();
myDynamicClass.myId = "some string";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are typing it as a MovieClip so it will always be a MovieClip unless you either create it as a MyWishClass or type it as that:

```
public class MyWishClass extends MovieClip{
    public var myId:String;
}
```

Then elsewhere:

```
public var myDynamicClass:MovieClip = new MyWishClass();

MyWishClass(myDynamicClass).myId = "test";
```

OR create it as:

```
public var myDynamicClass:MyWishClass = new MyWishClass();
```